# Editing Sharepoint "workflow status" page

Tags: sharepoint-designer

I'm new to using SharePoint designer and was wondering if there is any possible way one can add a column within the workflow status, "Tasks" area?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Out of the box SharePoint doesn't provide any option to add columns in that page. In SharePoint On-Prem version this page `wrkstat.aspx` comes from the 14 hive folder (based on the SP version you use), which is in the server. However, as you know, in SharePoint Online, we are unable to access server side which is controlled by Microsoft. So, currently, there is no way to do that in SharePoint Online.

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/a2537658-c12c-49c8-9c71-4ff4262b9df8/how-to-add-workflow-status-task-field?forum=sharepointgeneralprevious

Comment: Thanks for your response! I use on-prem and thought maybe SP Designer could allow this, but it sounds like this is not possible.

Comment: If you are using on-prem, then the link I have given you might help.

Comment: If my answer helped you, kindly upvote and Mark it as answer, so that it will help others too.